# setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE) and System TrayIcon

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, system, tray

How can I show the java application that I make after I Close my application?
I mean i want to close the application that I make, after that it still run on the background process (tray) and I did, but how can i make the application show (pop up) again after i double click my tray icon ?
Anyone can help me please ?

```
public MainMenu(String access) {

    this.access = access;
    initComponents();
    customInit();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    requestJobList("ALL");  
    setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    createReminder();
}



private void customInit(){

    joblistTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(rootPaneCheckingEnabled);

}

private void createReminder(){

  String icoPath = "C:/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/MOADesktopBaru/src/com/mayora/image/MOA.PNG";

  if(!SystemTray.isSupported()){
    System.out.println("System tray is not supported !!! ");
        return ;
    }
    //get the systemTray of the system
    SystemTray systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(icoPath);

    //popupmenu
    PopupMenu trayPopupMenu = new PopupMenu();


    //1t menuitem for popupmenu
       MenuItem setting = new MenuItem("Setting");
        setting.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                SettingFrame SF = new SettingFrame ();
                jDesktopPane.add(SF);
                SF.show();                         
        }
        });     
        trayPopupMenu.add(setting);

        //2nd menuitem of popupmenu
        MenuItem close = new MenuItem("Close");
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);             
        }
        });
        trayPopupMenu.add(close);

        //setting tray icon
        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "MOA Desktop", trayPopupMenu);
        //adjust to default size as per system recommendation 
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

        trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2)
        {
            initComponents();
            customInit();
            setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            requestJobList("ALL");  
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         }
        }
    }); 

        try{
            systemTray.add(trayIcon);
        }catch(AWTException awtException){
            awtException.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` shouldn't be placed inside tray icon listener.

To be able to show your app again by doubleclicking in its tray icon just add to the `mouseClicked()` method this line:

```
setVisible(true);
```

Note that what you are making visible again is the JFrame, so if you need to specify it just add it before your `setVisible(true)` method. Btw, since the app is already executed (in background), you don't need to call again `initComponents()` method.

Another suggest, don't use `mouseClicked()` method. Use `mousePressed()` from [MouseListener Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) instead. Why? Sometimes you click so fast that the app detects `mouseDragged` event, so the click does not count. If you use `mousePressed()`, you guarantee that it detects both clicks.

Comment: and thanks for the suggestion, I barely know if we use mouseClicked can have a side effect like that